# Refused to compile or instantiate WebAssembly module because 'wasm-eval' is not an allowed source of script

Tags: javascript, html, angular, content-security-policy, webassembly

I try to include an Adobe xD Prototype in an Iframe in an Angular app and by doing so I receive this error:

```
[Report Only] 
Refused to compile or instantiate WebAssembly 
module because 'wasm-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy 
directive: 
"
script-src 
https://static.adobelogin.com/imslib/imslib.min.js 
https://prod.adobeccstatic.com/ 

'self' 'unsafe-eval'

https://bam.nr-data.net/ 
https://api.demandbase.com/ 
https://js-agent.newrelic.com/ 
https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ 
https://c.evidon.com/geo/country.js 
https://assets.adobedtm.com/ 
https://use.typekit.net/ 
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js 
https://*.adobe.com 
https://*.cookielaw.org/ 
https://*.onetrust.com/ 'nonce-a5e5d635-4062-43de-b73a-04a9599d3d1a'
".
```

I don't even have created a content policy so far. The error appears as soon as I include the src-link:

```html
<iframe 
  src="https://xd.adobe.com/embed/9e081b15-b13d-4217-4cf9-8838d58e1ce9-e839/">
</iframe>
```

How could I solve it? Is it related to content security policies?

You can also check out the error if you open this [Stackblitz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/iframe-issue-web-assembly?file=src/app/app.component.css) and inspect the preview with the browser development tools.

Comment: It seams to be working fine in the `StackBlitz` you've provided.

Comment: The error does not appear in the StackBlitz console but appears if you open the development tools by inspecting the preview.